# UITextView content going under UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` inside a `UIViewController` that uses auto layout to pin it to 0 on all sides (so it fills the whole screen). I also have this view being pushed using `UINavigationController`.

I'm running into a weird error where if the `UITextView` has enough text so that it runs off the screen, then content gets set under the `UINavigationBar`. If there is not enough text to fill the screen the layout of the text doesn't go under the `UINavigationBar`.

Here is what's happening, this is when there is enough text that it goes off the screen and you need to scroll to view all of it.

[image]

I've tried:

- Setting the content inset of the `UITextView`.
- Made sure the `UINavigationBar` isn't translucent.
- Tried setting this `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

Answer (score 2):

Inside viewDidLoad of viewController where your textView is, add this:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It just gets the text stuck under the UINavigationBar :( thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Have you tried setting both   self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;  and   self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; ?
If it puts text stuck under navigationBar, i guess adding content insets to textView will bring it bellow navigationBar

Comment: Yeah I've tried that also but it doesn't work. What's even stranger is that setting the content inset still has no effect. It still starts under the `UINavigationBar`. When I scroll it down though the content inset is set. I've also tried `scrollRangeToVisible` which also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the problem was occurring but this fixed it:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    if (self.textView) {
        [self.textView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
    }
}
```